# Permission denied to connect Mongodb with PHP on EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, mongodb

I can't connect to the remote EC2 server with PHP because I got permission denied. However I could connect remotely by command line from the same server so it seems the firewall settings are fine and the bindIp is correct as well so it seems only the PHP has this connection issue.
The server is:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question, as written, doesn't seem to be a question as it contains its own resolution. If you would like to answer your own question, then please edit this question so it only contains a question, and then provide an answer with all applicable steps to resolve the issue. Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer), and don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. It seems the `httpd_can_network_connect` is off by default.

Run this command to enable:

`$ sudo /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

And restart the Apache:

`$ sudo apachectl restart`